# What is the name of the page "Change Opportunity Owner"?

Tags: opportunity, opportunity-teams, owner

I'm not developper but need to find the name of the page which displays when we click on "Opportunity Owner" to change the owner of the opportunity (see image). How i can find it into developper? What is name of this page pleeease? I looked for "Ownership Edit" found into forum, but nothing appeared under this name. [image]
Can you help me with this please?
Many thanks

Comment: Did you look at the URL shown in the browser's address bar?

Comment: It's a pop up modal so there won't be any URL or page name for you to get/use.

Comment: Exact, any URL displayed :-((

Comment: You can always look at the browser's inspector's network usage to see what URLs are being interacted with. However, I suspect this is just a built-in dialog and not a page that you can modify.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot @Phil and Kris.